# Active storage images not showing in activeadmin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Using active storage to store images which are working fine.
Issue I face is that when I `image_tag image` it shows `#` instead of image.

Here is the code
products.rb

```
has_many_attached :photos
```

in active_admin

```
row "Images" do |p|
  p.photos.attachments.each do |photo|
    image_tag photo
  end
end
```

it not displaying images. it check with byebug also the url is fine but images not display and it shows this

[image]

only this one works

```
row "Images" do |p|
    image_tag p.photos.attachments.last
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `url_for` to display the images, something like below

```
row "Images" do |p|
  ul do
    p.photos.each do |photo|
      li do
        image_tag url_for(photo)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: i updated my answer render image inside a `ul & li ` can you try that once? It worked for me.

Comment: but whats the diff?

Comment: i'm not sure but i think as you're looping through multiple items  it was returning an array of `#`. Where as when you use `last` you're directly rendering it with a `image_tag`. And when you use `ul & li` to render multiple items html is returned and it was rendering it. that makes the difference i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I did not face any issues doing it this way for multiple attachments:

```
if resource.photos.attached?
  row "Photos" do |resource|
    resource.photos.map{|photo| image_tag url_for photo}
  end
end
```

I don't know why @uday would suggest `ul` and `li`. It seems like an "XY solution".

Comment: I mean the OP was missing `url_for`. The issue is not solved with `ul` and `li`. It is solved with `url_for`.